# Swagger not able to authenticate to Azure AD B2C

Tags: swagger, azure-ad-b2c, swagger-ui

I have a Web API with a Swagger and an Azure AD B2C tenant.

A React app is able to obtain a token from B2C like:

```
          msalInstance.loginRedirect({
            scopes: ["openid", "offline_access", process.env.MY_CLIENT_ID],
          });
```

However the Swagger Authorize function returns `AADB2C90205`, `This+application+does+not+have+sufficient+permissions+against+this+web+resource+to+perform+the+operation`

The `AddSwagger` code in `Startup.cs` is:

```
        private void AddSwagger(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var azureAdB2C = new AzureAdB2CSettings();
            this.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", azureAdB2C);
            var authUrl = $"https://{azureAdB2C.TenantName}.b2clogin.com/{azureAdB2C.TenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/{azureAdB2C.SignUpSignInPolicyId}/oauth2/v2.0";

            services.AddOpenApiDocument(
                document =>
                    {
                        document.AddSecurity(
                            "bearer",
                            Enumerable.Empty<string>(),
                            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                                {
                                    Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                                    Description = "Azure AAD Authentication",
                                    
                                    Flow = OpenApiOAuth2Flow.Implicit,
                                    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
                                                {
                                                    Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
                                                                   {
                                                                       Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            $"{azureAdB2C.Instance}/{azureAdB2C.ClientId}/user_impersonation",
                                                                                            "Access Application"
                                                                                        },
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            $"{azureAdB2C.Instance}/{azureAdB2C.ClientId}/access_as_user",
                                                                                            "Access as User"
                                                                                        },
                                                                                    },
                                                                       AuthorizationUrl = $"{authUrl}/authorize",
                                                                       TokenUrl = $"{authUrl}/token",
                                                    },
                                                },
                                });

                        document.OperationProcessors.Add(new AspNetCoreOperationSecurityScopeProcessor("bearer"));
                    });
        }
```

The B2C configuration is as follows:

[image]

[image]

Am I missing anything obvious here?

Comment: It seems that there is a lack of permissions. Parse your token and provide screenshots.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to call web api projected by Azure AD B2C, please refer to the folloiwng steps

a. [Register web api application in Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-web-api-dotnet?tabs=app-reg-ga)
[image]

b. Define scope

c. [Register SPA application in Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-spa)
[image]

[image]

d. [Grant Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-web-api-application?tabs=app-reg-ga#grant-permissions).

e. application

1. package

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI
NSwag.AspNetCore
```

2. appsettings.json

```
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://<>.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
    "ClientId": "<web api clinet id>",
    "Domain": "<>.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_test"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // snip
      services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));

    // Add security definition and scopes to document
    services.AddOpenApiDocument(document =>
    {
        document.AddSecurity("bearer", Enumerable.Empty<string>(), new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            Description = "B2C authentication",
            Flow = OpenApiOAuth2Flow.Implicit,
            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
            {
                Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
                {
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            { "https://<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/your-api/user_impersonation", "Access the api as the signed-in user" },
                            { "https://<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/your-api/read", "Read access to the API"},
                            { "https://<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/your-api/mystery_scope", "Let's find out together!"}
                        },
                    AuthorizationUrl = "https://<b2c_tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=<policy_name>",
                    TokenUrl = "https://<b2c_tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=<policy_name>"
                },
            }
        });

        document.OperationProcessors.Add(new AspNetCoreOperationSecurityScopeProcessor("bearer"));
    });

    //snip
    
    // ...
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseOpenApi();
            app.UseSwaggerUi3(settings =>
            {
                settings.OAuth2Client = new OAuth2ClientSettings
                {
                    ClientId = "<spa client id>",
                    AppName = "swagger-ui-client"
                };
            });

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

f.test
[image]
[image]

For more details, please refer to the [blog](https://jpda.dev/using-nswag-and-swagger-ui-with-b2c).

Comment: I've been at this for 4 days straight.  This is the first thing that's worked.  Man, I owe you a beer or a case or something.  THANK YOU!!!